# Getting frames from WebCam

Tags: c#, camera

I am using class WebCam from MetriCam library, and I need to periodically get frames from my WebCam, anyone knows how to do that?
Here is code I already have:

```
namespace MetriCam_Coding_Example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region Private Fields
        private WebCam camera;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            camera = new WebCam();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!camera.IsConnected())
            {
                camera.Connect();
                buttonConnect.Text = "&Disconnect";
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                camera.Update();
                pictureBox1.Image = camera.CalcBitmap();
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            camera.Disconnect();
            buttonConnect.Text = "&Connect";
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a timer that every 200ms takes frame from pictureBox1.Image.

Answer (score 0):

You probably run into issues when trying to draw the Bitmaps too fast. The 200ms delay just makes these problems less likely but doesn't really solve it. You could try this code to skip frames that cannot be drawn:

```
namespace TestGUI
{
public partial class TestGUIForm : Form
{
    private IAsyncResult setBMPResult;
    private Webcam;

    private delegate void SetBmpDelegate(Bitmap b);

    /// <summary>
    /// Standard constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public TestGUIForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormClosing += TestGUIForm_FormClosing;

        cam = new WebCam();
    }

    private void TestGUIForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorkerGetFrames.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cam.IsConnected())
        {
            // if we are already connected, just disable the button and cancel the display thread, the actual disconnection takes place in the *_RunWorkerCompleted method.
            buttonConnect.Enabled = false;
            backgroundWorkerGetFrames.CancelAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            // connect the camera and start the display background worker.
            buttonConnect.Enabled = false;
            try
            {
                cam.Connect();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection error: " + ex.Message);
                buttonConnect.Enabled = true;
                return;
            }
            buttonConnect.Text = "Disconnect";
            backgroundWorkerGetFrames.RunWorkerAsync();
            buttonConnect.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorkerGetFrames_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (!backgroundWorkerGetFrames.CancellationPending)
        {
            // capture a new frame
            cam.Update();
            // get the current frame
            Bitmap bitmap = cam.CalcBitmap();
            // set the picturebox-bitmap in the main thread to avoid concurrency issues (a few helper methods required, easier/nicer solutions welcome).
            this.InvokeSetBmp(bitmap);
        }
    }
    private void InvokeSetBmp(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        if (setBMPResult == null || setBMPResult.IsCompleted)
        {
            setBMPResult = this.BeginInvoke(new SetBmpDelegate(this.SetImage), bmp);
        }
    }

    private void SetImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Bitmap oldBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBoxImageStream.Image;
        pictureBoxImageStream.Image = bitmap;
        if (oldBitmap != null && oldBitmap != bitmap)
            oldBitmap.Dispose();
    }

    private void backgroundWorkerGetFrames_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // disconnect camera and re-enable button.
        cam.Disconnect();
        buttonConnect.Text = "Connect";
        buttonConnect.Enabled = true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DispatcherTimer` with the time you whant. Its a timer interruption.

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 20); // 20ms
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer.Start();
```

Then when the timer tick it will reach in the event, and you get the image from you camera.

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    camera.Update();
    pictureBox1.Image = camera.CalcBitmap();
}
```